# If Pythagorean triples are $a<b<c$ , will $( c - a ) ( c - b )$ always be $2^p$?

Tags: number-theory

I have come to know that Pythagorean triples' behaviour is unique in this way after verification.

Comment: What about $(a,b,c)=(9,12,15)$ or $(a,b,c)=(8,15,17)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a, b, c$ can be generated by $k(u^2-v^2), 2kuv, k(u^2+v^2)$ (with $a \geq b$ possibly), the product $(c-a)(c-b)$ can be generated by $2k^2(u-v)^2v^2$, and is therefore not guaranteed to be a power of $2$.

It does have to be twice a square, though, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Your verification hasn't been particular extensive. A counterexample is $7, 24, 25$.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience;  it shall be ' 2(p^2) ' in place of  ' 2^p '

Comment: Then the other answer contains what you need.